# Introduction to mockito-python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I've been searching around on internet for online introductions to python-mockito, but there isn't so many resources available at this moment, their documentation seem very "for not-beginners" to me.

I saw many more content creating mock objects on python with unittest, but I applied for a job and they are requiring the mockito-python framework.

At this moment I don't know much about software test, they asked me to do unit and acceptance tests, where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their documentation, mockito-python is based on [Java Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) you can go through the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.11/org/mockito/Mockito.html) of mockito to understand the basic. There are a bunch of tutorial and documentation available on mockito. For example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/index.htm

Once you understand the basics you can use it with python.